# Is it safe to handle a denarian coin indirectly?

Tags: lore, dresden-files

I'm currently a new player in a campaign which does have a Denarian in it and has OOC had jokes made about my PC being tricked into touching one of their coins, which has made me curious and want to ask:

Is there anything in the setting on if it's safe to touch a denarian coin *indirectly?*

Such as if the character is wearing gloves, or were to try pick it up with something like tweezers/tongs- would that result in any infestation and count as "touched/picked up" or be perfectly okay for someone to do since it's not direct skin to metal?

Comment: Do you have a Crown Royale bag?

Comment: @Verdan no and I unfortunately have to admit, that I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @Verdan what it be alright to possibly ask about the Crown Royale bag and what it might do/offer in the case of this question?

Comment: it's an obscure reference to Dresden Files, that's about it really. I mean he was using one to carry the coins at one point, so I guess maybe it's relevant?

Comment: @trogdor alright, thank you for the clarification! Definitely another sign I should really get to reading the books soon then. :)

Comment: no problem, I read a bunch of them but I stopped at some point a few books after the coins were introduced, just glad I could help a little with some of the stuff I still remember from them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is exactly how it works in the setting (at least in the books, the RPG should most likely work the same way) touching the coin directly will 100% infect you and presuming you don't want that you would have to remove it (I forget exactly how that is done). Presuming you don't want that, and you need to transport one, **AND** you didn't already get infected (if you did you might as well carry it normally until you presumably take care of that problem), picking it up with a cloth that isn't thin enough for you to accidentally make skin contact, with gloves, or best of all tongs or some other device that can hold it further away from you can be used to keep it from infecting you.

Comment: There is no way to remove a Denarian 'infection' short of taking up the coin.  Once the shadow is in your head, you're stuck.  (Dresden 'corrupted' the shadow into not being a denarian anymore, but she's still there, at least in part, despite self-lobotomizing to protect him)

Answer (score 3):

### [The Coins](https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Blackened_Denarius) are shown to require skin contact to 'sink their teeth in'.

Michael Carpenter is shown to pick up a coin using "a square of white blessed cloth bearing two pairs of crosses embroidered with silver thread to pick up and transport the coins to the Church for safekeeping."; " However, Dresden and others have safely carried one or more coins through more mundane means, such as gloves to prevent direct skin contact, or storing them in a bag." This occurs most notably in

> Death Masks and Small Favor. Michael is even shown to pick up Thorned [Namshiel](https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Namshiel)'s hand, still holding a coin, and stowing it that way.

---

[It has been discussed](https://www.reddit.com/r/dresdenfiles/comments/4i2y7d/if_nicodemus_threw_a_coin_at_harry/) from time to time (and a GM may go either way) whether "touching" the coin initially requires willfully picking it up or any skin contact (ie having it thrown at you) works. [Jim Butcher has not clarified](http://wordof.jim-butcher.com/index.php/word-of-jim-woj-compilation/woj-on-angels-demons-fallen-and-knights-of-the-cross/) if you have to literally pick up a Coin or not.

As it's phrased in the summary of [Small Favor](https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Small_Favor)'s final scene,

> [Dresden's subconscious decides to pick up the coin in place of the child](https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Lasciel)...